# What is going on with the Unity Application Block project?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

For years I've been using the Unity container for dependency injection and interception in a fairly large project. Since 2012 we are stuck in the 2.1 version of the library, which works fine. I thought it would be worth taking a look at what Unity's been up to lately.

I came back confused. Currently, the [original Unity homepage](http://unity.codeplex.com/) states that the project has been sourced to the community and moved to a [Github repository](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity). That's all OK with me. But then I asked the most basic question: what/where is the latest version of the library? I found three different answers:

1. The Github repo [lists three 3.5 releases](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/releases), all of them Release Candidates (aka not really usable). No previous versions.
2. The NuGet Gallery hosts a certain [4.0.1 stable version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/) of the library which is not even mentioned in the now official Github project page.
3. The deprecated Unity Code Plex home page advertises the 3.5 version while the [downloads page](http://unity.codeplex.com/releases) lists version 3 as being the latest one.

The documentation is even more fragmented. The official GitHub project has none of it, while the NuGet package points to the old CodePlex site. Which turns out being the only reliable(ish) place to find docs and samples.

It frankly smells fishy. Does anybody have a clue about what's going on? Should we move out of Unity already? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 2017-01-31

It seems after about a year and a half with no commits, Unity still has some life in it and has released version 5.x. Unfortunately, at the present there is still no documentation for the new version from the new maintainers, just the old documentation from Microsoft.

### Original Answer

The very first link at the [original Unity homepage](http://unity.codeplex.com/) has [your answer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/):

> The .NET community has a rich history of dependency injection containers, dating back before the introduction of Unity. Dependency injection containers for .NET have continued to mature and evolve significantly. In addition, open source components are now more accepted. **The need for having an “official” container from Microsoft is no longer as widespread as it once was.** We did spend a few months in 2014 thoughtfully experimenting for a “Unity 4”. However, we began to recognize that the p&p team was not equipped to carry the project forward.
>
> At the same time, we believe that it would have been a poor choice to simply call the project “done”. We wanted to support all those who had invested in the library. After consulting with internal teams and p&p alumni, we asked Pablo and Pedro to assume the mantle.

*(emphasis added)*

Being that the feature set and ease of development with Unity has long been surpassed by other front runners such as [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html), and [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/), IMO using Unity "just because that is what the examples on MSDN do" is not a good enough reason to stick with it. Unity is [not even the container of choice in the brand new ASP.NET core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/03/28/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core/), so [its future is looking uncertain](https://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/the-future-of-unity) at this point.